# Showing an infimum of an expression involving alternating series is positive in a given variable as another variable tends to infinity

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, numerical-methods, convex-optimization, estimation

Let $\Bbb D$ be the unit disc in the complex plane. For the last month or so, I have been trying to prove that, if $\lambda \in \Bbb D$, and if $n \geq 4$ is an integer,

$$\inf_{\lambda \in \Bbb D}\Big[\frac{1+|\lambda|^2}{2} + Re(\lambda)\Big[1 -  \frac{(2\pi)^{2}}{(n+2)(n+3)}+\frac{(2\pi)^{4}}{(n+2)(n+3)(n+4)(n+5)}-...\Big]-Im(\lambda)\Big[\frac{(2\pi)}{(n+2)} -  \frac{(2\pi)^{3}}{(n+2)(n+3)(n+4)}+...\Big]\Big]$$

$\textit{decreases}$ to $0$ as $n \to \infty$, but that for any fixed $n \geq 4$, this infimum is always positive. I have been able to prove it along the coordinate axes within the disc, and in quadrants 1,3,4 of the disc. What remains is quadrant 2, which for obvious reasons makes the estimate more difficult.

I know that the first series converges to $1$ as $n \to \infty$, and the second series converges to $0$ as $n \to \infty$. I also have used wolfram alpha extensively to work on this, which has shown that for $n$ as large as I have entered,  the statement holds.

Empirically, all the evidence stacks up in my favor, but I can not rigorously show what I need to show here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following partial answer only shows that the infimum above is positive, and does so in a bit of a hack-y manner. An elegant answer would be interesting.

---

Let $\alpha_n$ and $\beta_n$ be the expressions multiplied respectively by $x$ and $y$ in the question. We first show that $\alpha_n^2 + \beta_n^2 < 1$ for $ n \ge 4$.

Note that $\alpha_n$ and $\beta_n$ are defined by alternating sums of monotonically decreasing terms (since $2\pi \le 7 \le n+3$), ergo, they're alternating series. This lets us use the upper bounds by truncation. For instance, $$\alpha_n < 1 -\frac{(2\pi)^{2}}{(n+2)(n+3)}+\frac{(2\pi)^{4}}{\prod_{j = 0}^3(n+2 + j)} $$ $$ \beta_n < \frac{2\pi}{n+2} - \frac{(2\pi)^3}{\prod_{j = 0}^2(n+2 + j)} + \frac{(2\pi)^5}{\prod_{j = 0}^4(n+2 + j)} $$

This form is messy but possible to attack computationally - it merely requires calculating the roots of some $8^{th}$ degree polynomial. Define $$f(n) := \left(1 -\frac{(2\pi)^{2}}{(n+2)(n+3)}+\frac{(2\pi)^{4}}{\prod_{j = 0}^3(n+2 + j)} \right) ^2 + \left(\frac{2\pi}{n+2} - \frac{(2\pi)^3}{\prod_{j = 0}^2(n+2 + j)} + \frac{(2\pi)^5}{\prod_{j = 0}^4(n+2 + j)} \right)^2,$$ and use your favourite package to determine when $f(n) < 1$. For instance, [Wolfram Alpha tells me](http://tinyurl.com/ju2t5jj) that $f(n) <1$ for $n \ge 3$, and since the bounds above hold for $n \ge 4$, we have that $\alpha_n^2 + \beta_n^2 < f(n) < 1$ for $n \ge 4$.

---

Next, we calculate the infimum. Note that

$$ \frac{1 + x^2 + y^2}{2} + \alpha x - \beta y = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{x^2 + 2\alpha x + y^2 - 2\beta y}{2}$$ $$= \frac{1 + (x + \alpha)^2 + (y - \beta)^2}2 - \frac{\alpha^2 + \beta^2}{2}$$ If $\alpha^2 + \beta^2 < 1 $, then the above is minimised at the point $(-\alpha, \beta) \in \mathbb{D}$, since otherwise at least one of $(x + \alpha)^2$ or $(y -\beta)^2$ is positive. Since we know that $\alpha_n^2 + \beta_n^2 <1$, $$ c_n := \inf_\mathbb{D} \frac{1 + x^2 + y^2}{2} + \alpha_n x - \beta_n y = \frac{1 - (\alpha_n^2 + \beta_n^2)}{2} > 0$$

---

Comment: Wow! Thanks alot! I have a few questions. First of all, the first infimum you calculated I was not able to find. I used Wolfram, entered everything correctly, triple checked, and it was not able to give me an answer. Could you explain how you found such an infimum? Secondly, forgive me if I missed it, but does this show that this infimum in fact decreases to 0? Certainly it goes to 0, but decreases?

Comment: Oh, my bad, I missed the decreasing bit, the above only shows that it's always positive. I'll add both the bits you mentioned.

Comment: Okay, there were some issues with the earlier answer (I should've been more careful with my calculations :) ), which are now fixed. Wolfram didn't give you the previous answer because the answer itself depends on whether $\alpha^2 + \beta^2 \le 1$ or not. I've updated this bit and included the correct answer. Fortunately this didn't change too much of what I had typed earlier.

Comment: My expressions quickly got super messy when I tried to show that the infimum was decreasing. I'll give it another shot in a bit, but unfortunately something else has come up for now.

Comment: Okay, so, estimates of up to $3$ terms like agbove do yield that the infimum is decreasing for $n > 34$. If you're only interested in the answer, then try using something like 5 or 6 terms in the alternating sum upper bounds for $\alpha_{n+1}^2 + \beta_{n+1}^2- \alpha_n^2 - \beta_n^2$, something should pop out. However, this is essentially hacking at the problem very crudely, and would be of limited insight. In case you'd prefer an...

Comment: (contd) elegant answer - $\alpha_n$ & $\beta_n$ are probably expressible as generalised hypergeometric functions in $n$, and I think someone better at analysis of the same might have a shot at getting somewhere. Perhaps a question on just this is warranted? (Do let me know if you ask one, I'm interested as well).

Comment: Sorry, I was off the site for a few days. Am reviewing your answer again now. Thanks so much for your time!

Comment: I actually think the answer your provided is quite enough the answer the overall question I was pursuing. I will keep this in mind for the future though if more elegance or detail is required. Thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome, glad to be of help :)